# jQuery mouseover mouseout event on a <span> when hover over a div

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, onmouseout, ismouseover

I am trying to make a title appear and disappear over a thumbnail. This is my title span:

```
<span class="thumbtitle"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
```

This is inside an `<li>` tag with a class of "thumb".

The jQuery i am using is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
  //settings
  var opacity = 0, toOpacity = 1, duration = 0;
  //set opacity ASAP and events
  $('.thumbtitle').css('opacity',opacity).hover(function() {
      $(this).fadeTo(duration,toOpacity);
    }, function() {
      $(this).fadeTo(duration,opacity);
    }
  );
});
</script>
```

Now this works perfectly, but it works when i hover over the title... i would like it to trigger when i hover over the thumbnail rather than where the title is positioned, so that when the mouse goes over the thumbnail (anywhere on it) the title appears.

Can someone help me do this? Also, can i give it an animation effect.. so that it gradually appears and disappears, rather than just instantly appear and disappear?

Miro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the updated one :-

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function() {
   //settings
   var opacity = 0, toOpacity = 1, duration = 0;
   //set opacity ASAP and events
   $('li.thumb').hover(function() {
      $(this).children('.thumbtitle').fadeTo(duration,toOpacity);
    }, function() {
      $(this).children('.thumbtitle').fadeTo(duration,opacity);
    }
  );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you... its "almost" works... The thumbnails load WITH the title already on them... once i hover over them, the effect seems to 'activate'. From then on, when i hover off, the title disappears and when i hover on, the title appears.

Comment: see my comment above... i would like the titles to show only when you hover over the thumbnail... i don't want them to show on pageload.

Comment: the code is written as if that it shows on hovering over. Test and let me know if it doesn't work. And obviously initially you have to hide that thumbtitle either from css or from js.

Comment: the best way is just in css add this in your stylesheet `.thumbtitle { display: none;}`

Comment: cool.. actually I previously thought it was done hence didn't mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it show on pageload, set the initial opacity to 0, and set it to 1 when hovered on...

Comment: Yeah that is. Subhajit forgot to add that, if you add that there should be no problem..

Answer (score 0):

Acording on the title of you question, i suposed that you html looks something like this

```
This is the thumbnail:
<div class="thumbnail">
    <li class="thumb">
        <span class="thumbtitle">Title<span>
    </li>
</div>
```

Check this out:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EJNCZ/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Start with no title visible.
    $('.thumb').hide();

    //settings
    var opacity = 0, toOpacity = 1, duration = 0;
    //set opacity ASAP and events

    $('.thumbnail').hover(function() {
        $(this).children('.thumb').fadeTo(duration , toOpacity );
    }, function() {
        $(this).children('.thumb').fadeTo(duration , opacity );
    });
});
```